# JPA Managed Entity: Is a searched Entity still a Managed Entity

Tags: java, jpa, entity, managed

If an entity, which I have with Query.getSingleResult found even a Managed Entity.
Can I make changes to it and it must not entityManager.merge or persist () call.

```
EntityManager em = ...
TypedQuery<User> query = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email = :userEmail");
query.setParameter("userEmail", "user@test.de");
User user = query.getSingleResult();
// change the user name and email
user.setName("Test1");
user.setEmail("test1@test.de");
// that all???
```

Answer (score 2):

You've fetched it through the `EntityManager` and you haven't detached it, so yes, it's still a managed entity and any changes you make to it will be written through to the database.

Comment: It was my pleasure Mulder3.